# Strategies for multicore builds (/MP) that use #import

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, build-process, multicore

I'm working on a new solution configuration for our large VC++ project using VS 2008. I'd like this configuration to use the multicore build flag [/MP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385193.aspx).

However, the "#import" feature of generating COM wrapper classes is sprinkled through-out the code base and this feature is not supported when using /MP.

I understand why #import won't work, **I want to know if anyone has faced this issue and how they worked around it?**

I am doing the following:

- Not use the /MP flag on projects that are small or ***beyond*** help. (maybe I'll come back to them later)
- Removed the #import and replaced it with a more standard MIDL-generated header (#include). This is only an option in a few places that are easy to convert to old school COM.
- Make a new project that #imports the remaining libraries. Make that build first. #Include the .tlh files it creates in all the places that #imported previously.

I'm curious if anyone has **any other suggestions?** Also, on the **last point** (making a new project and using #import only there) - if you did something like this, **how did you do it?** What type of project, what did the "source" look like, where did you output files? How did you include them? (you know, do all the thinking for me!)

Comment: your last option seems like the best way to go about it if you want multicore builds - it is consistent and no wasted work.  Sorr that I can't help with details about it,

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Turns out I'll need several stages of tlh generation at different stages of the build (a near hopeless battle). I've put this on hold - my current battle is to move off of VSS.

Comment: Here is your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650578/replacement-for-import-in-visual-c

Answer (score 12):

I have a project with two source files which #import the same file.  When compiling with /MP, it would occasionally get an access denied error since both source files were trying to create the .tlb at the same time.  I correct this by enabling pre-compiled headers, and adding the #import into the pre-compiled header source file.

Comment: This worked for me. Not sure if there are any downsides, but for now I'm happy. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the /MP option for the project as a whole, and then make an exception for a single file using the ***/MP1*** option.

Comment: In VS 2017, just turned off the /MP for the file(s) that contain #imports